# Filtering in angularJs on an object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to filter few records based on a list that is in my UI. But I am querying the DB where I am getting extra details other than what I am displaying in UI. How can I restrict my search to only to the properties of object which I am displaying in UI.

eg. I am querying DB and getting firstName,lastName,age and marks . but In UI I am only displaying the firstName and marks,So When in search box I write lastName it should not display anything.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Make some research, try some code and ask again where you fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` filter in angularjs may take an object as its filter expression:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:{firstname : searchtext}">
```

this returns only items where the `firstname` property contains the searchtext.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter for more information

Comment: Hi Nikolas, Thanks for reply.the filter i am trying to use comprise of both the firstname and marks.

Comment: you can use a comparator function for more complex filtering. in your controller you define: `$scope.comparatorFn = function (actual, expected) { return (actual.firstname.indexOf(expected) !== -1) || (actual.marks.indexOf(expected) !== -1); };` and in the view you use the comparator function as: `<li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:earchtext:comparatorFn">`

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-repeat="obj.firstName for obj in objects"
```

In your ng-repeat show only the fields you want using obj.firstName